# One ServiceHost, two end points (net.tcp & basic http)

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

I've got working netTcp host working; we are trying to add support for Mac and so are adding BasicHttpBinding. Ultimately, I'd like to use the same ServiceHost to do this, but when I try to browse to http://localhost:8085/Lss/test (test is an OperationContract I've got designed just to output some text) it responds with "400 Bad Request." What am I missing?

This is hosted as a Windows Service. Here is how the App.config setup looks:

```
  <service name="Wcf.Lss" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding" contract="Wcf.ILss"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="Wcf.ILss" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="9655360" maxBufferSize="9655360" maxBufferPoolSize="524288">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength = "932000" maxStringContentLength="900000" maxDepth="32"/>
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehavior" >
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The host is configured this way:

```
var baseTcpUri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8080/Lss");
var baseHttpUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8085/Lss");
var host = new ServiceHost(wcfSingleton, baseTcpUri, baseHttpUri);

host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true, HttpGetUrl=baseHttpUri });

var throttlingBehavior = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentCalls = 50;
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentInstances = 10;
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentSessions = 10;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttlingBehavior);

host.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't browse to an operation, you can only browse to the service which in your case is hosted at the base address. So, when you browse to "http://localhost:8085/Lss" you should see the standard WCF test page.